# Is there any Mac OS X app that I could use to show my Google Calendar on a Desktop?

Tags: software-recommendation, calendar, google-calendar

I would like to show a Google Calendar right on my desktop (possible one of them, not the one I'm using most often). Is there any app that I could use to do that?

Comment: You mean like a gadget on the desktop ?

Comment: Yes, but I need full (Mon-Sun) calendar, preferably filling the entire screen width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for something that shows more than GeekTool with iCalBuddy, then the following apps may help:

1. [CrisCalen](http://www.kenji-ootani.net/criscalen/criscalen.html) (currently a free app)
2. [Blotter](http://wireload.net/products/blotter/) (paid app)
3. [TimeWorks](http://www.goiser.com/timeworks) (paid app)
4. [Desktop Calendar](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/desktop-calendar/id499467082) (paid app)

See more at [30 of the Best Calendar Apps and Utilities for Mac](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/productivity-roundups/30-of-the-best-calendar-apps-and-utilities-for-mac/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the combination of [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) and [iCalBuddy](http://hasseg.org/icalBuddy/) (which you can install using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)).

On my desktop, it currently looks like this:

[image]